# Does Google Cloud Api Gateway provide request signing and verification sdk like signing AWS API Gateway requests using Signature 4?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

On Google Cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method), it mentions signed requests but it doesn't provide any further information. Does anyone know if Google Cloud Api Gateway provides such functionality?

The API is available for non-logged in users so I cannot use JWT authorization.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, no, only API Keys or identity based token (jwt) are allowed. However, a JWT is signed, but it's not AWS SigV4

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I see. do you know any good way to secure an API that is available to non-logged in users?

Comment: What do you mean by "secured" if the user aren't known/logged? Against what do you want to protect your app

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere to protect our APIs or resources from being misused easily by scripting

Comment: You can use API Keys, and only system that know the key can access to the API. ou can also, with API Keys and API Gateway set rate limits. It's per API Key.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere API Keys is more for tracking and usage limiting purpose. It is not for security. You can read it up on the document. Fyi, It is easily retrievable by inspecting the network.

Comment: Absolutely. The better solution is to have a short lived token, with cryptography mechanism to ensure the security. In your use case, which system should sign/secure the API call? Is it on the user browser? Is it another backend service?

Answer (score 1):

- Signed requests using Signatures can only be used to access Cloud
  Storage resources through XML API endpoints. Signatures (with V4
  signing) are one method for authenticating requests being sent to the
  Cloud Storage XML API. Signatures are used, for example, when working
  with signed URLs , signed requests and HTML forms. Here is the
  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures) link regarding this.
- API gateway however uses only API keys,  service account and JWT as
  authentication methods to validate incoming requests before passing
  them to your API backend as mentioned by guillaume blaquiere. Here is
  the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method) link.
- API gateway uses [JWT](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt), [Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-firebase), [Auth0](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-auth0), [Okta](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-okta) and
  [Google ID Token](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-googleid) to authenticate users.
- In addition to authenticating end user requests, you may want to
  [authenticate services](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticate-service-account) (non-human users) that make requests to
  your API. We can do this using :
  - Create a service account with a private key file that the
  calling service uses to sign the JWT.
  - Create an [API config](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/creating-api-config) for your gateway, you specify a
  service account that your gateway uses to interact with
  other services.In order to enable the service account
  authentication for services calling your gateway, modify
  the [security requirement object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityRequirementObject) and [security
  definitions object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityDefinitionsObject) in your API config.
- We can also secure access between API Gateway and the backend
  services. You can prevent public access to your backend managed
  services by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/securing-backend-services) link

If you are concerned about the security of API keys which are primarily used by API gateways for authentication, there are several ways also you can [restrict API access](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys) with these keys. However it is always recommended as a best practice to use signed JWTs or tokens as API keys are typically accessible to clients, making it easy for someone to steal an API key. Once the key is stolen, it has no expiration, so it may be used indefinitely, unless the project owner revokes or regenerates the key.